# Culture and language

Tags: language-change

Could you give some examples of how cultures affect languages? It is comprehensible that languages reflect cultures. It would be really helpful if you could provide with at least an example of cultures affecting the way we speak.

Comment: This sounds like a (rather boring) homework assignment.

Comment: This question seems to be far too broad. Would [polite particles](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/4423/1009) of Thai language match your criteria?

Comment: I haven't heard of them!

Comment: I know it is a broad question. But I fail to fully comprehend the way culture affects language. That is why I thought some examples would help me.

Answer (score 2):

The [politeness dances](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/119175/15299) undergone by European personal pronouns are a good example of a culture affecting a language. Another would be the rapid changes made to Old English while it was spoken mostly by peasants after the Norman invasion.

This would be a comment above, except that I am no longer allowed to make comments, for some reason, so I'm testing to see whether answers are similarly occluded.

Edit: Apparently not. But I still can't enter comments. Ah, well.

Comment: Apparently now I can enter comments. Hurray.

Answer (score 1):

At one time in Japan it became rude and offensive to protrude one's lips while speaking, it considerably affected the sounds of Japanese, eliminating the sound [f] in all the environments except before [ɯ].

Comment: Is this historical fact, or is a story that someone invented to explain the rarity of initial f in Japanese?

Comment: @fdb - It is a historical fact. I'll try to find the source now.

Comment: Any references?